# how to Pass Array in Objectmapper?

Tags: swift, objectmapper

Following format, I have to pass through objectMapper

[
    {
         "CartDataTableId": 19,
   }
]

following Code For ObjectMapper

```
class getCartChrgesPostData: Mappable {

    lazy var CartTableDataId         : Int? = 0


    required init() {
    }
    required init?(map: Map) {
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        CartTableDataId              <- map["CartTableDataId"]
    }
}

    func getDeliverYCharges(){
        for name in MyCartVC.objCartResponse.GetCartdetails! {
            let objRequestModel2 : getCartChrgesPostData = getCartChrgesPostData()
            objRequestModel2.CartTableDataId =  name.CartTableDataId!
            // let parameters = [["CartDataTableId": name.CartTableDataId!]] as [[String : Any]]
            let objCartDataProvider: CartDataProvider = CartDataProvider()
            objCartDataProvider.getCartChargesMethod(objRequestModel: objRequestModel2, IsLoader: true, viewController: self) { (responce, IsSucess) -> Void in
                if IsSucess! {
                    print(responce?.GetCartdetails!)
                } else {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

by using above methods I'm passing data but it sending as 
[
         "CartDataTableId": 19,
   ]

Comment: Please include code for CartDataProvider and any debugging output.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to send an array of `getCartChrgesPostData` objects as JSON parameter:

```
[
  {
    "CartTableDataId" : 19
  }
]
```

Instead of an getCartChrgesPostData object:

```
{
    "CartTableDataId" : 19
}
```

You can use the `toJSON()` and `toJSONString()` functions on an array of `getCartChrgesPostData` objects like:

```
let object = getCartChrgesPostData()
object.CartTableDataId = 19
print([object].toJSONString(prettyPrint: true) ?? "")
print([object].toJSON())
```

And the resulting JSON will be the desirable.

Hope this helps.